# how to set text middle on ActionBar android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hey all It may be asked several time before but I want to set text middle to a Action Bar
I have used following code to get that done..it doesn't help..

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<center>" + "<b>" + "Sign Up" + "</b>"
                + "</center>"));
```

bu when I use   then my purpose is fulfilled any accurate answer.

Comment: Please give answer before you vote down.

Comment: "It may be asked several time" : it has been, so why didn't you refer to those questions ? A simple Google search will returns dozens so why add a new one ?

Comment: I said may be..i am not sure about that...and i tried code i already shared so please may you check where i am wrong

Comment: the title textview is not full width of action bar, and it is not placed on middle of actionbar. to place title in center, you have to create custom actionbar layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView customView = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom_title_view_centered,null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

customView.setText("Your centered text");
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView, params);
```